# How to disable seemingly random syntax higlight in Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

Can anyone suggest:

1. Why does it higlight like this? I don't seem to do anything to activate it:

[image: screenshot]

2. How to disable it?

Comment: Does it say PHP under the Language menu? Maybe the file extension is making it think its something else and not PHP. This sometimes happened when I had projects with things like `.inc` or `.template` files

Answer (score 5):

This is old, but I ran into the same problem and just figured out an easy fix.

From the file menu: Language > N > Normal Text

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue as mine, but I wanted to keep the language setting enabled but remove the highlighting.

I did this by going to Settings --> Preferences --> Highlghting

Removed the Enable check mark for Highlight Matching Tags.

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to settings -> Style Configurator.

2) Select the language that Notepad++ has chosen, usually based on filename extension.  You can also change this manually under the **Language** menu setting.

3) Go through the Styles until you find the style that applied the highlighting. You can tell because the **Background colour** will match the highlighted color.

4) Change Background colour to white.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer for your first question

For your second question do the following steps
Inside Notepad++ press <kbd>ctrl A</kbd>( select all)
Right click for context menu.
select `Remove style` and click on `Clear all Styles`

This will clear all the  highlights.

Comment: Tnx, but this didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

FYI. You may also see this sort of behavior when using a vertical edge in background mode. Switching to line mode will eliminate the highlighting of lines that run over the set character count for the vertical edge.